# I can no longer initialize a React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

For a long time now, it has been impossible for me to initialize a react project, or even to initialize a project with npm because of multiple errors that I cannot resolve. Initially, it started from my versions of npm and node js that I had to update. I uninstalled create-react-app globally and then I reinstalled it. But when I launch the creation of a react project with create react app I have the following errors

```
glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'scandir',
path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
} 
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"

Creating a new React app in /home/tiffane/Documents/Visi/client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'scandir',
path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-       template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting client/ from /home/tiffane/Documents/Visi
Done.
```

after reading the errors obtained I performed an npm cache clean --force history to clean things up, I tried to initialize react in root mode, I entered the command sudo chown -R 1000: 1000 "/ root /.npm "as indicated, but nothing to do I still can not initialize my project react

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Reinstalling node and npm helped.
Try removing node.js completely with:

> sudo apt-get purge node

It removes the package and all the configuration files. Then download the latest stable version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/).
That should solve the issue.
Later to update node you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: after purge it, should i reinstall it whitout anytings???

Comment: node is not an package

Comment: @DevBeginner What do you mean? Are you getting some kind of error??

Comment: after purging node, i re install node whith the last version..but i get the same error

Comment: @DevBeginner Then I have no idea what might be wrong. Sorry, I couldn't help, I'm not very experienced with Linux. Try asking the question in Linux forums. Your Linux distro probably even has some specialized forums you can make use of.